# Live Streaming Freeze after some time in android?

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

i am using vitamio lib to play online video in my app.
but when i use this link for playing

```
path = "http://94.242.221.141/hls/a-lo/stream140.m3u8";
```

i works fine for one or two min. after that video sopts/freeze.

my logcat output is (when video stops)

```
04-10 18:57:11.972: I/Vitamio(7341): Info (901, 120)
04-10 18:57:11.972: D/Vitamio(7341): onInfo: (901, 120)
04-10 18:57:15.144: D/Vitamio[Player](7341): [http @ 0x5f233e80] HTTP error 404 Not Found
04-10 18:57:15.152: I/Vitamio(7341): Info (901, 38)
04-10 18:57:15.152: D/Vitamio(7341): onInfo: (901, 38)
04-10 18:57:16.066: D/Vitamio[Player](7341): [http @ 0x5f233e80] HTTP error 404 Not Found
04-10 18:57:18.808: D/Vitamio[Player](7341): playback complete (0, 0)
04-10 18:57:19.011: D/Vitamio(7341): onCompletion
```

other links are working fine.
could any one tell any solution.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

i have found an app

```
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.livetv.russia&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmxpdmV0di5ydXNzaWEiXQ..
```

in this app russia today live tv is playing.
i searched on google and found links for live streming

```
http://ixinji.com/iblog/2012/08/29/online-live-tv-list-for-apple-tv%EF%BC%8Ciphone-and-ipad/
http://livetvstreaming.ucoz.com/news/russian_complete/2013-03-23-5618
http://westsat.net.ua/archive/index.php/t-2894-p-2.html
http://www.tvdata.eu.pn/index.php/database/exportsimpletv
http://www.tvdata.eu.pn/index.php/database/exportvlc
```

i am using

```
http://94.242.221.141/hls/a-lo/stream140.m3u8
```

for live streaming but after one or two min my app stop working or video freeze.

Comment: Problems with exactly this stream on remote server side?

Comment: Did you wait for more then 2 minutes? (in other app)

Comment: This must be mentioned in your question's body (about other apps)

Comment: @Andremoniy please have a look on edit